# How to configure the way to generate composite pk with JPATOOL

Tags: jpa

I'm develop based on jpa 2.0 with Eclipse Luna, I see that for a composite pk JPA TOOL always generate a pk class as a property of the parent entity, but for some reason I wanna multiple pure properties for composite pk in entity, no need for a pk class.
pls take a look at what I have done.
[image]

then entity codes generated as below:
[image]

[image]

the ddl of table user_info(mysql) is as below:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `user_info` (
>   `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `birth_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`first_name`,`last_name`)
> )
> ```

what I want is no pk class to generate ,only the entity class with simple type pk fields like only one-field pk,it should look like :
[image]

but jpa tool plugin doesn't give me a chance to select the pk generating way, how can I implement it with jpa tool or any other plugin?

Thanks

Kurt

Comment: Eclipse does not support any other way of mapping your composite primary key. Also note: you will still need to define an `@IdClass`, which is much like an `@EmbeddedId` class but not as clean.

Comment: Hello Brian, is there any other kind of plugin which can generate entities and be configured the way of mapping composite pk? I don't want @IdClass either, only want simple type pk fields.

Comment: I don't know of any other plug-ins that don't simply re-use or extend the Dali plug-in, which is the plug-in that provides the Entities from Tables wizard you are using. Also: the JPA spec _requires_ you to use either an `@EmbeddedId` or `@IdClass` if you have a composite primary key. (Personally, I prefer using `@EmbeddedId`. `@IdClass` is a remnant of earlier EJB persistence specs.)